# Web application with python

Tags: python, web

I have a Python program that takes one input (string) and prints out several lines as an output. I was hoping to get it online, so that the web page only has a text-area and a button. Inserting a string and pressing the button should send the string to python and make the original page print out the output from Python.

Assuming I have only dealt with Python and a little bit of HTML and have very limited knowledge about the web, how might I approach this problem?

For some reason, my first instinct was PHP, but Googling "PHP Python application" didn't really help.

That is, assuming what I want IS a 'web application', right? Not a web server, web page or something else?

How could I get a really simple version (like in the first paragraph) up and running, and where to learn more?

Comment: A "web application" is a vague handwavey term to encompass and describe everything that goes into some "service" that lives on the web. Yes, you want that. But you also want just a simple web server, which will respond with a "web page". There's no need to throw PHP into the mix. Look into Python web servers, e.g. Flask.

Comment: PHP is a programming language. A "PHP Python application" doesn't make much sense (it could be an application written in both PHP and Python, but why bother with the additional complexity).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the term you're looking for is "web application". Specifically, you want to host a Python web application.

Exactly what this means, can vary. There are two main types of application - `cgi` and `wsgi` (or stand-alone, which is what most people talk about when they say "web app").

Almost nobody uses cgi nowadays, you're much more likely to come across a site using a web application framework, like Django or Flask.

If you're worried about easily making your page accessible to other people, a good option would be to use something like the free version of Heroku do to something simple like this. They have a guide available here:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#introduction

If you're more technically inclined and  you're aware of the dangers of opening up your own machine to the world, you could make a simple Flask application that does this and just run it locally:

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def main():
    return 'You could import render_template at the top, and use that here instead'

@app.route('/do_stuff', methods=['POST'])
def do_stuff():
    return 'You posted' + request.form.get('your string')

app.run('127.0.0.1', port=5555, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pick a Python web development framework and follow the getting started tutorial. Main options are [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) for a "batteries included" approach or [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) for a minimalistic bottom-up approach.